# ASM and duplicate condition check, why?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

I have disassembled my test C program, this is a part of the code I'm not sure if I understood correctly.

```
00401143: 83 F8 01           cmp         eax,1
00401146: 0F 84 F4 00 00 00  je          00401240
0040114C: 85 C0              test        eax,eax
0040114E: 0F 85 A0 00 00 00  jne         004011F4
00401154: 31 C0              xor         eax,eax
```

So basically, this is what I understand:

1. Check if `eax` equals `1`, if yes return `0`
2. If `0`, jump to `00401240`, if not, continue
3. Test == AND thus I already know it will return `1` because there is no way eax can equal `0` as it would jump on `00401146`. **I was wondering** why should I call this `test`. Why can't I simply replace `test` **and** `jne` with single `jmp` (non-conditional jump) which we would reach only if `eax` equals `1` anyway.
4. If not `0` (thus `1`), jump to `004011F4` -- this will always happen
5. We will never reach `00401154` from this point (we can assume then that there must be call/jump) somewhere in the code which would navigate us to `00401154`

Is this correct or is there something that I haven't understood correctly?

Comment: `je` would fall through if `eax!=1`, and then `test` would give you a `eax>1` true or `eax==0` false, which would then be used to `jne` or fall through...  What does the C code for this disassembly look like?

Comment: The sequence cmp eax,1 | je 401240 will take the jump if eax == 1. Unless somewhere else in the code there is a jump to 401154, the xor eax,eax is not needed, since the only way to get there is if eax == 0 in the text eax,eax | jne 4011F4 sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be simply badly optimised code by the compiler, but to explain what it has done, while being thorough it added the bitwise "test" to look for any other value except for the 1 you were initially looking for.

The compiler has generated code to evaluate whether EAX is 0 or 1 and strictly no other value.

```
if(a==1){...}
else if(a<>0){...}
```

...

```
00401143: 83 F8 01           cmp         eax,1     ...EAX is 1?
00401146: 0F 84 F4 00 00 00  je          00401240  ...EAX is 1...
0040114C: 85 C0              test        eax,eax   ...EAX is strictly 0? (eax & eax)
0040114E: 0F 85 A0 00 00 00  jne         004011F4  ...EAX is another value
```